# Effect of destroying OK, CANCEL and HELP windows of a porperty sheet

Tags: c++, mfc, dialog, cpropertysheet

I wanted to use a CPropertySheet based application for a project and I did not want those default OK, Cancel, Help and Apply buttons that come with a CPropertySheet class. Therefore, I destroyed those windows on OnInitDialog. Here is the code for reference:

```
BOOLCProductUI::OnInitDialog()
{
    CPropertySheet::OnInitDialog();

    CRect rect;
    CButton *pTempBtn;
    CButton SaveChanges;

    pTempBtn = reinterpret_cast<CButton *>(GetDlgItem(IDHELP));
    if (NULL != pTempBtn)
    {
        pTempBtn->GetWindowRect(&rect);
        pTempBtn->DestroyWindow();
    }

    pTempBtn = reinterpret_cast<CButton *>(GetDlgItem(IDOK));
    if (NULL != pTempBtn)
    {
        pTempBtn->DestroyWindow();
    }

    pTempBtn = reinterpret_cast<CButton *>(GetDlgItem(IDCANCEL));
    if (NULL != pTempBtn)
    {
        pTempBtn->DestroyWindow();
    }

    pTempBtn = reinterpret_cast<CButton *>(GetDlgItem(ID_APPLY_NOW));
    if (NULL != pTempBtn)
    {
        ScreenToClient(&rect);
        pTempBtn->MoveWindow(rect);
        pTempBtn->SetWindowText(_T("Save Changes"));
    }

    UpdateData(FALSE);
    return TRUE;
}
```

CProductUI is a class of CPropertySheet.
However, when I compile the program using VC++2008 in Debug mode, I get a Debug Assertion Failed  error message at the line
"**CPropertySheet::OnInitDialog();**"
*Can anyone please shed some light on why this is happening?*

Comment: **Assert message** should help you to understand what problem is. In general don't _destroy_ them, just hide.

Comment: My first action was to destroy them. I realized that the DestroyWindow() would have caused some problem but then, I commented those calls and tried running my application using ShowWindow(SW_HIDE) still, I am met with the same Debug Assertion in Debug mode.

Comment: What's exact error message? Together with line numbers (in same message) it should highlight what's wrong.

Comment: The Debug Assertion Failed error message box contains the following Program: (path of my exe)                                                                                 File: f:\dd\vctool\vc7libs\ship\atlmfc\include\afxcmn.inl                                                                 Line: 268

Comment: LOL yes, I have MFC source code but as you can see there are many ASSERT in OnInitDialog(). Which one fails?

Comment: How do I find out which one failed? Does the line number 268 indicate the line number in the MFC Source code?

Comment: LRESULT CWnd::Default()
{
 // call DefWindowProc with the last message
 _AFX_THREAD_STATE* pThreadState = _afxThreadState.GetData();
 return DefWindowProc(pThreadState->m_lastSentMsg.message,
  pThreadState->m_lastSentMsg.wParam, pThreadState->m_lastSentMsg.lParam);
}                                                                                                                   Here is where the assertion fails.

Comment: Isn't a form designed by you + CMFCTabCtrl a more adequate solution for your interface?

Answer (score -1):

Per [How to Hide the Apply Button in CPropertySheet](http://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/141039). Destroying window is not a proper solution to hide default buttons of property sheet. I would suggest you to use **"ShowWindow()"**. But as you already mentioned your showwindow() also creating problem which is not possible if your calls are correct. Let it be, if your ShowWindow() is not working in "OnInitDialog()" function then better move this function to "OnCreate()". And also if it is not working then please share your whole .H and .CPP file.

Answer (score -2):

1. You should call `ShowWindow (SW_HIDE);` instead of `DestroyWindow();`
2. Also there is no need to cast `CWnd*` returned by `GetDlgItem()` to `CButton*`.
3. Please also comment out your `CButton SaveChanges;` declaration. You
   don't need it.

You can also use built-in flags to do that:

```
CMyPropertyPage myPage;
myPage.m_psp.dwFlags &= ~PSP_HASHELP;
myPropertySheet.AddPage(&myPage);

myPropertySheet.m_psh.dwFlags |= PSH_NOAPPLYNOW;
myPropertySheet.m_psh.dwFlags &= ~PSH_HASHELP;
```

**IMPORTANT:** In general please run your application in Debug mode to see where it ASSERTs.

Comment: Any way to undo the damage caused by my call to DestroyWindow() because after commenting the call to DestroyWindow() and then hiding the window, I still get the same error message. Could DestroyWindow() have tampered with the default settings of a Property Sheet?

Comment: Run the application in Debug mode (F5) and you'll see exact line where it ASSERTs in Debugger.

Comment: You also need to DISABLE any hidden buttons.  So in addition to calling `ShowWindow(SW_HIDE)`, you need to call `EnableWindow(false)` on the CWnd, otherwise buttons will still be "active" via tabbing and button text "&" accelerator key strokes.

Comment: The built in flags only work for Apply and Help buttons. Will I have to recreate my project all over again?

Comment: No, you don't need to recreate your project. Have you been able to identify the line where it ASSERTs?

Comment: LRESULT CWnd::Default()
{
 // call DefWindowProc with the last message
 _AFX_THREAD_STATE* pThreadState = _afxThreadState.GetData();
 return DefWindowProc(pThreadState->m_lastSentMsg.message,
  pThreadState->m_lastSentMsg.wParam, pThreadState->m_lastSentMsg.lParam);
}

Comment: Is your propSheet located in DLL? Are you using any custom controls? Are there any threads updating GUI?

Comment: I apologize for the late answer but after creating another identical project bit by bit i realized I hadn't called the CPropertyPage::OnInitDialog() function in one of my classes. It works perfectly fine now. Thank you so much for your time.